# Image issue in WordPad since latest Windows 10 feature update

Tags: windows-10, wordpad

I have a strange issue in WordPad. I have a document that I use as an e-mail footer; I prepare the complete text in WordPad, and when it is done, copy it into Outlook (2016 with O365 back-end, in case it matters), and send it off.

Since the latest feature update (Windows 10 version 1703, build 15063.540) I can reliably reproduce the following: open the document in WordPad, select all, copy (Ctrl-C), unselect, and the image at the bottom of the document will turn black or transparent in its entirety. This change persists through copy/paste, and as a result I have to close and reopen the document every time I write a new e-mail.

The test document can be found on PasteBin (https://pastebin.com/xrVyaKD7). Switch to raw view, copy the contents into a text file, make sure it is in ANSI encoding (not Unicode or UTF-8), and save it e.g. as test01.rtf, then open it in WordPad, and follow the instructions above.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**EDIT:** I thought I was pretty concise and clear but apparently people still manage to not understand what this issue is about. Let me try and make it clearer.

I load my document (see above link and instructions for recreating the same document) into WordPad:

[image: Document opened in WordPad]

I select the document contents:

[image: Documents contents selected]

I press Ctrl-C, minimize the WordPad window, and restore it again:

[image: Document contents copied, window minimized and restored]

Afterwards the image is either transparent or just gone. If I write something, copy all again, and paste it in a different application, the original image will not be there. I have to close WordPad, and reopen the document with it to restore the image.